# Vectorization on nested loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, nested-loops

I need to vectorize the following program :

```
y = np.empty((100, 100, 3))  
x = np.empty((300,)) 
for i in xrange(y.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(y.shape[1]):
        y[i, j, 0] = x[y[i, j, 0]]
```

Of course, in my example, we suppose that y[:, :, :]<=299
Vectorization, as far as I know, can't simply work here as we are using the native python indexing on lists ...

I've heard of `np.apply_along_axis`, but it doesn't work on this special case, or may I missed something ?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.apply_along_axis` could work, but it's overkill.

First, there's a problem in your nested loop approach. `np.empty`, used to define `y`, returns an array of `np.float` values, which cannot be used to index an array. To take care of this, you have to cast the array as integers, e.g. `y = np.empty((100, 100, 3)).astype(np.int)`.

Once you do that, you can index using `y`, as follows:

```
y = np.empty((100, 100, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
x = np.empty((300,))
y[:,:,0] = x[y[:,:,0]]
```

Of course, `y` is all 0's, so it's not quite clear what this accomplishes.

Comment: Care with `np.uint8`, `x` is already longer than `255` in your example.

Comment: @imaluengo, thank you for the comment. You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you must convert the y to type integer, since the default will be float (and thus cannot be used as indices). But can't you just do the following?

```
import numpy as np
y = np.empty((100, 100, 3))  
x = np.empty((300,)) 
y[:,:,0] = x[y[:, :, 0].astype(int)]
```